# Text wrap making each line go on top of one another HTML

Tags: html, text, word-wrap

I'm trying to write it so that the text on my blog won't overlap. I tried putting the "white-space: nowrap" code into everywhere that had text, but it just made the words go out into the middle of the page. Here's a link to my page illustrating what I'm talking about http://schlurb.tumblr.com/post/68525778003/life-goals-marry-paris-hilton-birth-a

Here's a part of the code I'm using:

```
.quote {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: {
    text: Body font size
  }
  px;
  line-height:20px;
  text-transform:none;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  width:620px;
  font-family: {
    font: body title
  }
  ;
}
```

Comment: Just put your html part as well which shows the above problem.

Comment: Aye the code you have linked is CSS which is useful but it would also be useful to see the HTML

Answer (score 0):

I think you encountered the collapse problem. This happens because of

```
float:right;
```

If really is the case you can solve it by adding

```
 overflow:auto;
```

to the parent of your quote.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm just going to say that the bit of CSS code you've posted above does not currently apply to anything on your web page. Why? Well, the code above applies to all elements with the class name "quote". You have no HTML elements on your page with the class "quote" assigned to it.

Go through and add the quote class to the applicable elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS .quote{} has no corresponding e.g. `<div>` tag, this after looking into the pagelink you provided